# Save SQL column value to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to save a value to an array.
I have a column called `numbers` values are `1,2,3`.

If I select this value, then save it into a variable `$value` and try to put it into an array:

> $array = array($value);

But its not working properly.

Comment: How are you selecting? Probably use `explode`. Also using `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: Can you give a var_dump of $value?

Comment: <?php
$array = array("1","2","3");
echo implode(" ",$array);

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL (you've tagged both, and it's very unlikely that this is correct)? Or does it not matter at all? Your question seems to be about how to handle your data in PHP, not in the database?

Comment: @GoogleMac string(7) "1,2,3 "

Comment: @alroc my fail...i have clicked SQL Server by accident^^ And yes I want to know how to handle the data in PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not automatically convert strings into integers. Your dump showed that it is one string, so do this:

```
// separate by the comma into array
$array = explode("," $str); // array( '1', '2', '3' );

// re-create an array, converting strings into integers
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    $array[$index] = (int)$value; 
}
```

Comment: `$final_array = array_map('intval',$array);` instead of foreach

Comment: @JYoThl, Yes, array_map is shorter code, but I was meaning to help the OPer understand what was going on..  Any who already understand it should use your snippet.